# javascript detecting file path

Tags: javascript, dirname

i am going to make a npm package that can check the main file if it's exist how can i detect the file path?

main file

**index.js**

```
  const exampleCheck = require("exampleCheck")

exampleCheck(__dirname);
```

**node_modules**

```
 const path = require("path");
 const fs = require("fs-extra");

module.exports = async function(file) {
  if (!fs.existsSync(path.join(file, "index.js"))) return console.log("index.js doesn't exist");
}
```

my **question** is why the **fs.existSync** on  my package at **node_modules**  always return **false** but the **index.js** is exist at the main file

i hope you understand my english haha please help me a lot

my package always says **index doesn't exist** but it's exist at the main file

finding the file path

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -2):

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

module.exports = async function () {
  // Find the main project directory using the parent module's __dirname
  const mainModule = module.parent;
  if (mainModule) {
    const projectDirectory = path.dirname(mainModule.filename);
    if (fs.existsSync(path.join(projectDirectory, "index.js"))) {
      console.log("index.js exists in the main project directory.");
    } else {
      console.log("index.js doesn't exist in the main project directory.");
    }
  } else {
    console.error("Could not determine the main project directory.");
  }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT). Posting AI-generated output is officially BANNED on Stack Overflow. If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then please delete it since [posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned). If not, then please add some description to the answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).